# Как работает vertical-align?

Tags: html, css, scss

Я верстаю сайт, в одном случае vertical-align сработал, в другом как мне кажется точно таком же - нет. Как мне в меню выровнять текст по центру при этом что бы высота блока равнялась 100%? Если что, я использую SCSS. Вот как оно работает:

```css
/*! normalize.css v8.0.1 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */

/* Document
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Correct the line height in all browsers.
 * 2. Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in iOS.
 */

 html {
    line-height: 1.15; /* 1 */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
  }
  
  /* Sections
     ========================================================================== */
  
  /**
   * Remove the margin in all browsers.
   */
  
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  /**
   * Render the `main` element consistently in IE.
   */
  
  main {
    display: block;
  }
  
  /**
   * Correct the font size and margin on `h1` elements within `section` and
   * `article` contexts in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.
   */
  
  h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0.67em 0;
  }
  
  /* Grouping content
     ========================================================================== */
  
  /**
   * 1. Add the correct box sizing in Firefox.
   * 2. Show the overflow in Edge and IE.
   */
  
  hr {
    box-sizing: content-box; /* 1 */
    height: 0; /* 1 */
    overflow: visible; /* 2 */
  }
  
  /**
   * 1. Correct the inheritance and scaling of font size in all browsers.
   * 2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
   */
  
  pre {
    font-family: monospace, monospace; /* 1 */
    font-size: 1em; /* 2 */
  }
  
  /* Text-level semantics
     ========================================================================== */
  
  /**
   * Remove the gray background on active links in IE 10.
   */
  
  a {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  
  /**
   * 1. Remove the bottom border in Chrome 57-
   * 2. Add the correct text decoration in Chrome, Edge, IE, Opera, and Safari.
   */
  
  abbr[title] {
    border-bottom: none; /* 1 */
    text-decoration: underline; /* 2 */
    text-decoration: underline dotted; /* 2 */
  }
  
  /**
   * Add the correct font weight in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
   */
  
  b,
  strong {
    font-weight: bolder;
  }
  
  /**
   * 1. Correct the inheritance and scaling of font size in all browsers.
   * 2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
   */
  
  code,
  kbd,
  samp {
    font-family: monospace, monospace; /* 1 */
    font-size: 1em; /* 2 */
  }
  
  /**
   * Add the correct font size in all browsers.
   */
  
  small {
    font-size: 80%;
  }
  
  /**
   * Prevent `sub` and `sup` elements from affecting the line height in
   * all browsers.
   */
  
  sub,
  sup {
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: baseline;
  }
  
  sub {
    bottom: -0.25em;
  }
  
  sup {
    top: -0.5em;
  }
  
  /* Embedded content
     ========================================================================== */
  
  /**
   * Remove the border on images inside links in IE 10.
   */
  
  img {
    border-style: none;
  }
  
  /* Forms
     ========================================================================== */
  
  /**
   * 1. Change the font styles in all browsers.
   * 2. Remove the margin in Firefox and Safari.
   */
  
  button,
  input,
  optgroup,
  select,
  textarea {
    font-family: inherit; /* 1 */
    font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
    line-height: 1.15; /* 1 */
    margin: 0; /* 2 */
  }
  
  /**
   * Show the overflow in IE.
   * 1. Show the overflow in Edge.
   */
  
  button,
  input { /* 1 */
    overflow: visible;
  }
  
  /**
   * Remove the inheritance of text transform in Edge, Firefox, and IE.
   * 1. Remove the inheritance of text transform in Firefox.
   */
  
  button,
  select { /* 1 */
    text-transform: none;
  }
  
  /**
   * Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
   */
  
  button,
  [type="button"],
  [type="reset"],
  [type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
  }
  
  /**
   * Remove the inner border and padding in Firefox.
   */
  
  button::-moz-focus-inner,
  [type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
  [type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
  [type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {
    border-style: none;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  /**
   * Restore the focus styles unset by the previous rule.
   */
  
  button:-moz-focusring,
  [type="button"]:-moz-focusring,
  [type="reset"]:-moz-focusring,
  [type="submit"]:-moz-focusring {
    outline: 1px dotted ButtonText;
  }
  
  /**
   * Correct the padding in Firefox.
   */
  
  fieldset {
    padding: 0.35em 0.75em 0.625em;
  }
  
  /**
   * 1. Correct the text wrapping in Edge and IE.
   * 2. Correct the color inheritance from `fieldset` elements in IE.
   * 3. Remove the padding so developers are not caught out when they zero out
   *    `fieldset` elements in all browsers.
   */
  
  legend {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
    color: inherit; /* 2 */
    display: table; /* 1 */
    max-width: 100%; /* 1 */
    padding: 0; /* 3 */
    white-space: normal; /* 1 */
  }
  
  /**
   * Add the correct vertical alignment in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.
   */
  
  progress {
    vertical-align: baseline;
  }
  
  /**
   * Remove the default vertical scrollbar in IE 10+.
   */
  
  textarea {
    overflow: auto;
  }
  
  /**
   * 1. Add the correct box sizing in IE 10.
   * 2. Remove the padding in IE 10.
   */
  
  [type="checkbox"],
  [type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
    padding: 0; /* 2 */
  }
  
  /**
   * Correct the cursor style of increment and decrement buttons in Chrome.
   */
  
  [type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
  [type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    height: auto;
  }
  
  /**
   * 1. Correct the odd appearance in Chrome and Safari.
   * 2. Correct the outline style in Safari.
   */
  
  [type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
    outline-offset: -2px; /* 2 */
  }
  
  /**
   * Remove the inner padding in Chrome and Safari on macOS.
   */
  
  [type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  }
  
  /**
   * 1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
   * 2. Change font properties to `inherit` in Safari.
   */
  
  ::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    -webkit-appearance: button; /* 1 */
    font: inherit; /* 2 */
  }
  
  /* Interactive
     ========================================================================== */
  
  /*
   * Add the correct display in Edge, IE 10+, and Firefox.
   */
  
  details {
    display: block;
  }
  
  /*
   * Add the correct display in all browsers.
   */
  
  summary {
    display: list-item;
  }
  
  /* Misc
     ========================================================================== */
  
  /**
   * Add the correct display in IE 10+.
   */
  
  template {
    display: none;
  }
  
  /**
   * Add the correct display in IE 10.
   */
  
  [hidden] {
    display: none;
  }
  
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/********** MY CSS **********/
body {
  background-color: #1c2228;
}

header {
  background-color: #161a1f;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
header .logo_container {
  float: left;
  background-color: #1F252C;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
}
header .logo_container * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
header .logo_container .logo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
header .logo_container .site_name {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
}
header nav {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
header nav ul {
  height: inherit;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
header nav ul li {
  height: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
}
header nav ul li a {
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
        <title>Тыж Программист</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="logo_container">
                <img class="logo"></img>
                <p class="site_name">Тыж Программист</p>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Меню1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Вот может надо SCSS:

```
            $default_text_color: #fff;
            $default_text_font: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;

            $menu_color: #fff;


            body {
                background-color: #1c2228;
            }
            header {
                $header_height: 80px;
                background-color: #161a1f;
                width: 100%;
                height: $header_height;

                .logo_container {
                    float: left;
                    background-color: #1F252C;
                    height: $header_height;
                    padding: 15px 15px;
                    * {
                        display: inline-block;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                    }
                    .logo {
                        width: 50px;
                        height: 50px;
                        background-color: #fff;
                        border-radius: 50%;
                    }
                    .site_name {
                        margin-left: 15px;
                        color: $default_text_color;
                        text-transform: uppercase;
                        font-size: 18px;
                        font-family: $default_text_font;
                    }
                }

                nav {
                    height: 100%;
                    display: inline-block;
                    ul {
                        height: inherit;
                        margin: 0px;
                        padding: 0px;
                        list-style: none;
                        li {
                            height: inherit;
                            display: inline-block;
                            a {
                                
                                vertical-align: middle;
                                color: $menu_color;
                                text-decoration: none;
                                text-transform: uppercase;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: такое делается через flex'ы

Comment: @GGO Ок. Но почему оно с vertical-align не работает то? Вообще это свойство когда я его пытался применять вело себя очень странно, то работая, то не работая.

Comment: свойство работает только для inline или для inline-block елементов + зависит от ситуации

Comment: @GGO ссылку я делал inline-block и так же не работало. Вообщем буду делать через флексы. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы вертикальное выравнивание сработало правильно нужно всем элементам внутри родителя явно указать свойство `vertical-align`, т.к. это свойство не наследуется, а применяется к каждому элементу отдельно.

В данном случае вы пытаетесь выровнять по центру `a` внутри `li`, но ему не от чего оттолкнуться, элементы выравниваются по центру относительно друг друга, но в данном случае элемент только 1.

Если не хотите использовать `flex`, то можно добавить небольшой костыль:

```
ul li::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 1px;
}
```

У этого метода есть явные недостатки, которые решаются с помощью `flex`, но возможно в вашем случае такой решение подойдёт.